# Unable to open read-only Environment

Tags: java, database, xodus

I'm trying to open a read-only Environment with:

```
  public Environment getReadOnlyEnvironment(String xodusRoot, String instance) {
    final EnvironmentConfig config = new EnvironmentConfig().
            setLogDataReaderWriterProvider("jetbrains.exodus.io.WatchingFileDataReaderWriterProvider").
            setLogCacheShared(false).
            setMemoryUsagePercentage(10);
    config.setLogLockTimeout(3000);
    Environment env = Environments.newInstance(xodusRoot + instance, config);
    return env;
  }
```

The problem is it keeps on throwing this error:

```
Caused by: javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: jetbrains.exodus.env: type=EnvironmentConfig, location=\var\xodus\master
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.Repository.addMBean(Repository.java:437)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerWithRepository(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1898)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerDynamicMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:966)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerObject(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:900)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:324)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.registerMBean(JmxMBeanServer.java:522)
    at jetbrains.exodus.management.MBeanBase.<init>(MBeanBase.java:36)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd consider this as a [bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/XD-816). To work around, turn management off: `EnvironmentConfig.setManagementEnabled(false)`.

Comment: The error went away but the database is not behaving normally, data fetched is inconsistent if not able to fetch data at all.

Comment: After digging more into this, I think I found the issue, it seems you cannot create two `Environment`s (meaning `newInstance` will throw) with one having write-access and the other with read-only access at the same time. So this defeats the purpose of a read-only environment.

Comment: I am guessing this is related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63965457/instancealreadyexistsexception-jetbrains-exodus-entitystore-type-entitystoreco

I will check again and get back to accept this post if it is.